# __unicode__() method doesn't work well

Tags: django, unicode, model

In models.py:

```
class POstan(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    shortname = models.TextField()
    map = models.TextField()
    man = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    woman = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    about = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    map_img = models.TextField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'p_ostan'
```

In views.py:

```
def select(request):
    list = PMenu.objects.all()
    os = request.META['PATH_INFO']
    os = os[8:]
    items = PShahr.objects.filter(ostan=os)
    farsi = POstan.objects.filter(shortname=os)
return render(request, 'select.html', {'list':list, 'os':os, 'farsi': farsi, 'items': items})
```

select.html:

```
{{ farsi }}
```

The output is this right now:

```
[<POstan: اصفهان>]
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
اصفهان
```

How should I do that?

Comment: farsi is basically a list that of objects that has returned after the filter query. In you template you need to loop through the objects and print the name of the each object. 
try this 
`{% for far in farsi %}`
`{{ far.name }}`
`{% endfor %} `

Comment: It works thank ou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had this display is because you use `filter` to get `farsi`, which gives you the result of a queryset. If you print queryset it looks like a list with `[]` around it. What you need is `get`:

```
farsi = POstan.objects.filter(shortname = os)
```

This would give you a single object and `{{ farsi }}` would only refer to `__unicode__` of a single object.